# Rectangular bar and wave 3dGraphics

Tags: graphics3d, rotation

I plot rectangular bar in 3D. with this bar I also draw a wave (Sin(x,y)). upon combining these graphs the waves appear in the vertical direction. I want to rotate it in the horizontal direction in the combined plot. Can anyone help?

````
a1 =
 RegionPlot3D[
  Abs[x] <= 10 && Abs[y] <= 10 && Abs[z] <= 10, {x, -1, 50}, {y, -1, 
   50}, {z, -1.1, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "x3"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[50], Brown]],
a2 = Plot3D[5 - Sin[(x + y)/4], {x, 11, 45}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  Extrusion -> 0.2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[50], Orange]]```

```Show[a1, a2]```
````

Comment: What is plot22 here? It seems that you only published a part of the code.

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention the code. Now I have updated the file/

Answer (score 2):

You may do almost as you did:

```
a1 = RegionPlot3D[
   Abs[x] <= 50 && Abs[y] <= 10 && Abs[z] <= 10, {x, -1, 50}, {y, -1, 
    50}, {z, -1.1, 10}, AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2", "x3"}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Brown]];
a2 = Plot3D[5 - Sin[(x + y)/4], {x, 11, 45}, {y, 0, 10}, 
   Extrusion -> 0.2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[50], Orange]];

Show[a1, a2]
```

yielding the following

[image]

I would do it a bit differently. Like this:

```
Show[{
  
  

    Graphics3D[{
    Blue, Opacity[0.5], Cuboid[{10, 0, 2}, {45, 10, 7}]}],

      Plot3D[5 - Sin[(x + y)/4], {x, 11, 45}, {y, 0, 10}, 
       Extrusion -> 0.2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[50], Orange]]
      }]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

you can further play around adding some elements and removing others.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Perhaps I  could not elaborate my question precisely. Actually, I want to plot the wave on the top of the rectangular bar. Keeping the shape of the bar intact unlike figure 1 above.